# How do I tell ScalaTest to run a class annotated with DoNotDiscover?

Tags: scala, scalatest

[ScalaTest 2.0](http://www.scalatest.org/) doesn't automatically run classes that extend [`Suite`](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.0/index.html#org.scalatest.Suite) but have been annotated with [`DoNotDiscover`](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.0/index.html#org.scalatest.DoNotDiscover). However, it *"will run classes annotated with DoNotDiscover if asked to explicitly, it just won't discover them."*

But how do I explicitly ask ScalaTest to run such a *DoNotDiscover* annotated class?

ScalaTest ignores all such classes although I specify them explicitly via `test-only`. Example: I have this test suite:

```
@DoNotDiscover
class AnonLoginSpecRunner
  extends org.scalatest.Suites(new AnonLoginSpec)
  with StartServerAndChromeDriverFactory
```

But when I do this:

```
[my-project] $ test-only test.e2e.specs.AnonLoginSpecRunner
```

ScalaTest says:

```
[info] No tests to run for securesocial/test:test-only
[info] Passed: : Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0, Skipped 0
```

What can I do to get ScalaTest to run my `AnonLoginSpecRunner`?

As a work around, I currently do this:

```
[debiki-server] $ test:console
scala> (new test.e2e.specs.AnonLoginSpecRunner).execute()
```

and that works, but it's a bit cumbersome and I'd like to avoid it.

(The reason I'm using `@DoNotDiscover` is I have a main suite that sets up the chrome driver once and for all, and then runs a list of all E2E test specifications.)

Comment: I posted this question [at the scalatest-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/scalatest-users/DoNotDiscover%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false/scalatest-users/l8FK7_I0agU/5ppcItVIsakJ).

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Or figure out a way for test-only to work, but not have it included in the normal `sbt test`?

Comment: @ericpeters No I don't think I ever did. Currently I have for other unrelated reasons replaced all my ScalaTest end-to-end test code with Webdriver.io and Typescript, and that works great. The e2e tests were the only ones that made use of `DoNotDiscover`. So I don't need it any more.  — I use ScalaTest for unit testing & "functional" testing though — and for that, I haven't needed `DoNotDiscover`. I do often type `test-only package.ClassName` though to test only one class. I like ScalaTest a lot :- )

Answer (score 4):

The solution I came up with was to create a shell script that ran the test through ScalaTest's "Runner", through SBT

so a simple `./sbtTestFoo.sh` script looks something like:

```
sbt "test:run-main org.scalatest.tools.Runner -o -s
com.foo.TestFoo"
```